# Javascript bug in simple comparison

Tags: javascript

This is really weird! There are two "if"s on my code for comparison two values

```
if(block>currblock)
{
    currblock++;
    console.log("currblock:"+currblock+" | block:"+block);
}
if(block<currblock)
{
    currblock--;
    console.log("currblock:"+currblock+" | block:"+block);
}
```

When code runs, it does mistake. For example I tested it with values block=13 and currblock=9. When I fire the code second "if" executes!

I used console log to make sure if values are correct or not. And the console  output is correct.

any ideas?

Comment: If `block`  is `<` (less than) `currblock` why would the second `if` condition not be satisfied? Last time I checked 9 is less than 13.

Comment: After your edit, I am absolutely not able to recreate the issue. The first if statement is always executed: https://jsfiddle.net/onw94p81/

Comment: Is it inside a loop?

Comment: I know this is weird. Maybe something about compiler is wrong. I asked for any ideas.

Comment: Yes. In a while loop.

Comment: that is why you get the error.. it is increasing currblock until it get greater than block then it begins to decrease currblock until it gets smaller than block and so on

Comment: @roberthofer At this point, the error lies in the code that's not part of the question. We might be able to blindly guess at what the problem is, but it's not likely we can find the solution without seeing more of the code (I think Marcus might be onto something though).

Comment: No. Loop will break when two values are equal at the begining and if you see my example (13 and 9) it happens anyway.

Comment: `Maybe something about compiler is wrong` - It's a poor craftsman that blames his tools

Comment: As Maximilian said, the error is somewhere else, the if statements alone couldn't get the second if to evaluate to true as it could never make curblock larger than 13. Please post a verifiable example.

Comment: Please provide more code context

Comment: Guys I think that's enough to explain error. As I said second if executes with values block=13 and currblock=9. Why this is happening when currblock is smaller than block??

Comment: It's happening somewhere else and as long as you hide the rest of the code, we can't help

Comment: @roberthofer - are you saying that piece of code runs both conditional blocks when block = 13 and currblock = 9?

Comment: Here you can see a screen shot of console. http://postimg.org/image/gcxa25fpn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parsing before ifs. Like so:

```
if(parseInt(block)>parseInt(currblock)) { 
    currblock++;
    console.log("1. currblock:"+currblock+" | block:"+block);
}
if(parseInt(block)<parseInt(currblock)) { 
    currblock--;
    console.log("2. currblock:"+currblock+" | block:"+block);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> not relevant since the screen capture posted

It appears your javascript is being 'interpreted as if you wrote

```
if(block>currblock);
{
    currblock++;
    console.log("1. currblock:"+currblock+" | block:"+block);
}
if(block<currblock);
{
    currblock--;
    console.log("2. currblock:"+currblock+" | block:"+block);
}
```

Perfectly valid, but not what you intended. Is something on the server adding ; where it shouldn't? look at your page source, or try reformatting your code to look like this - which you should do with javascript anyway becauseof the curse of the optional ;

```
if(block>currblock) { // <=== move this { to the if line
    currblock++;
    console.log("1. currblock:"+currblock+" | block:"+block);
}
if(block<currblock) { // <=== move this { to the if line
    currblock--;
    console.log("2. currblock:"+currblock+" | block:"+block);
}
```

Comment: it was a long shot, and your screenshot showed it couldn't be this

Comment: Maybe you could try parsing your vars to int before the ifs.... At this point, i'm guessing...

Comment: Marcus I think the problem is something like that. Let me try.

Comment: try make a snippet so we can see better what is going on

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
    var block = 13
    var currblock = 9;
    if(block>currblock){
        currblock++;
        console.log("currblock:"+currblock+" | block:"+block);
    }
    else if(block<currblock){
        currblock--;
        console.log("currblock:"+currblock+" | block:"+block);
    }
```